# Best way to handle table with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I usually deal with `Repeater` to generate tables in my asp.net pages, but now I need to handle **dynamic columns** in my table, so I wonder if there is a common approach to solve this issue using web controls.

I've never used `GridView`, so I don't know if this is better to render tables with dynamic columns? Can you suggest me wich is the more appropriate approach? Is there a way to achieve this using `Repeater`?

Answer (score 1):

You could a `GridView` with [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) set to true. It would inspect and add the columns in your `DataSource`

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSource"
  selectcommand="SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName FROM SalesLT.Customer"
  connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AWLTConnectionString %>" 
  runat="server"/>

<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
  datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
  autogeneratecolumns="True"
  emptydatatext="No data available." 
  allowpaging="True" 
  runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID">
</asp:gridview>
```

Comment: why do I hate sqldatasource  so much ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to know how you want to handle the situation.

**Situation 1:**
You have an existing table and from time to time you add columns (which is not very practical though) you can straight away go for the GridView and set the AutoGenerateColumns binding property to true.

**Situation 2**

You can create your own HTmlHelper Class for handling the tables.
For this you can visit the following post:

[How to create MVC HtmlHelper table from list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891372/how-to-create-mvc-htmlhelper-table-from-list-of-objects)

if you are using MVC.

Comment: OP mentions `Repeater`, which is a well-known ASP.NET WebForms control.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack to do this if you must use `Repeater`:

In the .aspx:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID='rptr' runat='server'>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>
                        Always visible header col
                    </th>
                    <th id='thHidable' runat='server' class='hideable'>
                        Hideable header col
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Repeated col
                </td>
                <td id='tdHideable' runat='server' class='hideable'>
                    Hideable repeated col
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody></table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

In the code behind (assuming C# used):

```
    protected override void Page_Init()
    {
        this.rptr.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptr_ItemDataBound);
    }
    void rptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)e.Item;
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            HtmlTableCell thHidable = (HtmlTableCell)item.FindControl("thHidable");
            if (hideCondition)
            {
                // thHidable.Visible = false; // do not render, not usable by client script (use this approach to prevent data from being sent to client)
                thHidable.Style["display"] = "none"; // rendered hidden, can be dynamically shown/hidden by client script
            }
        }
        else if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            HtmlTableCell tdHideable = (HtmlTableCell)item.FindControl("tdHideable");
            if (hideCondition)
            {
                // tdHideable.Visible = false; // do not render, not usable by client script (use this approach to prevent data from being sent to client)
                tdHideable.Style["display"] = "none"; // rendered hidden, can be dynamically shown/hidden by client script
            }
        }
    }
```

(optional) If you want to dynamically show column on client side (assuming it was rendered), using jQuery (for brevity):

`$(".hideable").show();`